# Instruction reordering on intel

Tags: c, assembly, x86, memory-barriers

I'm trying to understand the instruction reordering by the following simple example:

```
int a;
int b;

void foo(){
   a = 1;
   b = 1;
}

void bar(){
   while(b == 0) continue;
   assert(a == 1);
}
```

It's known that in this example the assertion may fail if one thread executes `foo`, and another one executes `bar`. But I don't understand why. I consulted the [Intel manual Vol. 3A, 8.2.2](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf) and found the following:

> Writes to memory are not reordered with other writes, with the
>   following exceptions:
>
> — streaming stores (writes) executed with the
>   non-temporal move instructions (MOVNTI, MOVNTQ, MOVNTDQ, MOVNTPS, and
>   MOVNTPD); and
>
> — string operations (see Section 8.2.4.1).

There are no string operations here as well as I did not notice `NT` move instructions. So... Why is the reordering of writes possible?

Or does the memory matters in

> Writes to ***memory*** are not reordered

? So when we have `a` and `b` cached and writes occur not to main memory, but to cache they can be.

Comment: Why do you think `a` and `b` will be stored in **memory**? There's no such requirement in C++ language, in corner case the compiler may generate code which will keep those two in registers only (for example).

Comment: @Ped7g Yes, I asked the wrong question... Sorry

Comment: No problem, searching the correct question is part of the process, and sometimes that process requires steps like this one. :) But the topic may be quite tricky, so you will have to be more precise to get some meaningful answer..

Comment: you need prevent here compiler reordering. say by insert `a = 1; _ReadWriteBarrier(); b = 1;` on x86/x64 this will be enough

Comment: Is this actually C or C++, or are you actually asking about assembly that does those operations in that order?  Because obviously this is UB in C, and the C memory model applies for compile-time reordering and load hoisting, not the x86 memory model.  IIRC, you did this in a previous question and wasted everyone's time sorting out C vs. x86 memory models, so **please specify in the question that you actually mean if the asm looks like this.**  Obviously `while(b == 0){}` will become an infinite loop with any normal C compiler if it enters the loop at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes The question was not about C compiler and static compiler reordering. I meant that `foo` and `bar` are executed by different threads. The line of `b` may be in exclusive state of the core the thread executing `foo` is running on and the line of `a` is in shared state on both cores. So the write to `a` is placed in a store buffer and read-invalidate is sent to the core 2 which may be discorvered later then `assert(a == 1)` is executed.

Comment: @St.Antario: Then don't tag it [tag:c] and post syntactically-valid C without any explanation that the code is *not* actually C.  *Or* fix your C to use release stores and acquire loads (which map directly to x86 instructions), or at least `volatile`.  You already wasted Bathsheba's time writing an answer about the UB.  (And BTW, just removing the `[c]` tag is only barely sufficient.  Everyone knows what C looks like, and that non-atomic variables can be optimized into non-shared registers, so that's a big distraction.)

Comment: @PeterCordes So in fact because of store buffer and cache coherence things the other thread observed writes made by `foo` in a different order. Yet in the manual I quoted is clearly said that writes to memory cannot be reordered with another writes.

Comment: If you *actually* did what you mean in x86 asm, seeing `b!=0` would guarantee that you also see `a==1`, because `mov [b], 1` is a release-store (like all x86 stores other than NT), because x86 requires stores to commit from the store buffer to L1d in program order.  (So reordering is *not* allowed.  Only compile-time reordering can break this example on x86).  But if you compiled this invalid C, then that's not the case.  Are you claiming that you actually reproduced the reordering you're talking about?  If so, post a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterCordes _If you actually did what you mean in x86 asm, seeing b!=0 would guarantee that you also see a==1_ So how about the case I described above? If `a` is still in a shared state and invalidated after it was read?

Comment: Only compile-time reordering can break this example on x86.  `a` can't *still* be in shared state after `b=1` is visible; that would mean the thread running `foo` let its stores reorder.

Comment: @PeterCordes No I am not claiming that. I tried to reproduce and could not. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @PeterCordes `a can't still be in shared state after b=1 is visible`. Can you provide a relevant quote from the intel doc?

Comment: @St.Antario: you already did: *Writes to memory are not reordered with other writes*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your premise is wrong.  Only compile-time reordering can break this example on x86<sup>1</sup>.

x86 asm stores are release-stores.  They can only commit from the store buffer to L1d cache in program order.

`a` can't *still* be in shared state after `b=1` is visible; that would mean the thread running `foo` let its stores commit out of order.  This is what *Writes to memory are not reordered with other writes* means, for stores to cacheable memory.

If it's in shared state *again* after being invalidated by the RFO from the thread running `foo`, then it will have the updated value of `a`.

---

Footnote 1.  Of course the spin-loop will optimize into `if (b==0) infinite_loop`, because data-race UB lets the compiler hoist the load.  See [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/387181/mcu-programming-c-o2-optimization-breaks-while-loop).

You seem to be asking about C rules while assuming that the code will be translated naively / directly to x86 asm.  You could get that with relaxed atomics, but not `volatile` because `volatile` accesses can't be reordered (at compile time) with other `volatile` accesses.

Comment: Like I already said I was mistakenly provided an example in `C` while meaning the x86 assembly.

Comment: @St.Antario: I re-added the C tag, because that's the only reason I can imagine for your claim that "*It's known that in this example the assertion may fail*".   See http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/, and http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/.

Answer (score 4):

If one thread was running `foo` and another was running `bar` then the behaviour of your program would be *undefined*.

You are not allowed to make simultaneous read and writes on a non-atomic variable such as `int`.

So instruction reording is permissible in this instance.

Comment: @RbMm If the are aligned correspondingly... But it's UB anyway.

Comment: yes, agree with alignment. but i not view any pragma in code which overwrite default alignment in this case. so assume natural alignment for int. and in this case not view any ub. of course need force compiler not reorder `a=1,b=1`